# find element by id in innerhtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an asp.net gridview with one column as a template filed with a panel with some controls like textbox and dropdown list.
So, onclick, with js I can give the value of a cell by row and column, but in this panel column how can I get the inner elements?

```
function t3(tab, element, NParents, col)
{
    //alert("t3")
    var grd = document.getElementById(tab);
    if (grd != null)
    {
        var row = element

        for (i = 0; i < NParents; i++)
        {
            row = row.parentNode
        }

        alert(grd.rows[row.rowIndex].cells[col].innerHTML)
    }
}
```

innerHtml give me the HTML of the panel, now how can I find its elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> but in this panel column how can i get the inner elements?

You can use `querySelector` to query the DOM element

```
var cell = grd.rows[row.rowIndex].cells[col];
var textbox = cell.querySelector( "input[type='text']" ); //will return input box inside the text
var select = cell.querySelector( "select" ); //will return dropdown inside the text
```

Comment: in case, i tried also 
var textbox = cell.querySelector("input[id='elementID']"); 
to find by id

Comment: You can directly do `cell.querySelector("#elementID");` ... In case of id you just need to give *# + id-value*